# Eclipse shows warning on Antlr generated code directory with no files, but not on its sub-directories

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 and Eclipse Luna (4.4.0). The directory `main` containing Antlr's generated code shows a warning icon, but the directory has no files, and its sub-directories do not show the warning icon. Therefore, I can't find what is causing this warning. Any ideas on how I can get rid of it?

[image: A warning icon on src even though it has no file and its sub-directories do not show a warning icon]

**Update**: after a suggestion in the comments, I found the warning. It was in a sub-directory `model` of `main`, which somehow does not appear in this particular view of `main`, but does appear on a duplicate view of `main` in the same project tree:

[image: A duplicate, collapsed view of <code>main</code> in the same project tree]

So I guess my main question now is why does Antlr appear in a separate, duplicate view instead of integrated with the rest of the code...

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion, I was forgetting that way of showing the warnings. I found the warning, which was placed in sub-directory of main that does not appear on this view of it, but does appear on a separate, duplicate view of it in the project tree. Odd.I will update the question with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second image shows the way how Eclipse represents source folders in the Package Explorer view. Source folders are folders where Eclipse looks for program sources, and is configured in Build Path / Configure Build Path project menu, or can be automatically managed by tools such as Maven.

The first picture is how this Eclipse view represents other files in the project folder that are *not* part of the build path. This view also omits everything that is on build path (it also by default hides any generated files such as built `.class` files).

Since the ANTLR grammar is in a folder that is not configured in your project to be a source folder, it is shown this way. Note that the grammar files are indeed not "sources" from Eclipse's point of view, since it ahs no way to compile it directly. It instead takes another tool to generate source files from the grammar, which then should be treated as sources by Eclipse.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I thought this was for the Antlr generated java files, but indeed it only contains grammar files.

Comment: It seems like it would be better not to place the grammar files under src, then, to avoid this confusion...

Comment: Well I use the same structure, it makes sense - sources for main (not test) to be placed in `src/main`. They *are* sources, just not *java sources* - and thus are not in `src/main/java` but in `src/main/antlr`.